# Swiper.js swipe on mobile and medium screen

Tags: responsive, swiper.js

Swiper.js works done on a large screen but in mobile doesn't work.

> init props

```
<Swiper
   effect={"coverflow"}
   grabCursor={true}
   centeredSlides={true}
   slidesPerView={"auto"}
   coverflowEffect={{
     rotate: 30,
     stretch: 0,
     depth: 200,
     modifier: 1,
     slideShadows: true,
     }} 
   >
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of proving why this is but pretty sure it's a bug with coverflowEffect.
I've just spent hours debugging this issue, and removing coverflowEffect fixes the slider. Once I reintroduce it, mobile swiping breaks again.

Comment: Answer would be better as a comment. It does not provide a solution but the information may be helpful nonetheless